# how do i share my comments to fb using socialize

Tags: android

how do I share my comments to facebook using socialize, I tried the following codes but it directly enters into the facebook home page its not sharing my comments...can anyone help me 
here is my code,

```
public class TraSocializeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String entityKey     = "http://www.getsocialize.com";
        Entity entity = Entity.newInstance(entityKey, "Socialize");
        View actionBarWrapped = Socialize.getSocializeUI().showActionBar(this, R.layout.main, entity);
        setContentView(actionBarWrapped);

        //this is the code for sharing my comments to facebook but its not working it allows the //user to enter the facebook directly
        if(Socialize.getSocialize().isAuthenticated()) {
            //Entity entity1 = Entity.newInstance("http://someurl.com", "My Entity");  
            String comment = "The comment to be added";
            ShareOptions options = new ShareOptions();
            options.setShareLocation(true);
            options.setShareTo(SocialNetwork.FACEBOOK);
            options.setListener(new SocialNetworkListener()
            {
                public void onError(Activity activity, SocialNetwork network, String message, Throwable e)
                {
                }
                public void onBeforePost(Activity activity, SocialNetwork network)
                {
                }
                {                         // Handle before post
                }
                public void onAfterPost(Activity activity, SocialNetwork network)
                {                         // Handle after post
                }
            });
            Socialize.getSocialize().addComment(this, entity, comment, options, new CommentAddListener()
            {
                public void onError(SocializeException error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
                public void onCreate(Comment comment)
                {                         // Handle success
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it "enters into the facebook home page" do you mean it shows a facebook login page?  If so, this is correct behavior.  The user must authenticate with Facebook to be able to give your app access to their Facebook account to post to their wall.

Answer (score 0):

I'll ping our devs to get you an answer tonight.  Sorry for the delay; just saw your question. - DROdio